# <h1> - <h6> Tags Rendered as Green Font in Email Newsletters

Tags: html, css, header, tags, dreamweaver

I'm designing an email in Dreamweaver with inline CSS, but every test I make, with Hotmail in Firefox and Chrome always renders header tags as a green font color. I want the font to be normal. Nothing will change it. Why is `<h1>`-`<h6>` rendered as a font color?

```
<div class="blockheader">
    <h2>New event starting today!</h2>
</div>

<style>
#block .blockheader {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What does the inline CSS look like? Also, have you tested with Hotmail only?

Comment: yes only Hotmail in both browsers and Apple Mail. Obviously Apple Mail has more support, but that's not what I am concerned about.

Comment: The styles you posted here don't look very inline, to be honest. You can't count on `<style>` elements in the body of the email to be handled the way you want, because `<style>` elements in the body are non standard, and many email clients may discard them. So use `style` attributes. See Jonathan's answer.

Comment: It sounds as though I have a lot more to learn. I haven't been using Dreamweaver or web technologies very long. Thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 8):

When writing HTML/CSS for emails, you tend to have to pretend you're going back in time. Meaning, write very basic markup, and use inline styles:

```
<h1 style="color: #FFF; background: #000">Foo Email</h1>
```

Additionally, check out the [HTML Email Boilerplate](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/). You may also find the [Inline Styler](http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/) to be of help too.

Comment: Ok, that's really great. Thank you for your help. I'll get right on that :)

Comment: Huh! On reading the link you posted, it mentions my exact symptom: "Hotmail header color reset: Hotmail replaces your header color styles with a green color on H2, H3, H4, H5, and H6 tags." Great ^_^

Answer (score 1):

In doing a little research, Hotmail renders h tags green and for no good reason that I see.  The fix that I found is using !important in your  in-line styles.  So like this:

`<h4 style="color: #660000 !important;">Awesome Red Header in Hotmail</h4>`

Hope this helps.